# prove if and only if logic equivalent to ($P\lor Q) \rightarrow (P\land Q $)(using the laws without truth table)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Given that the if and only if defines as being equivalent to $[ p \rightarrow q]\land [q\rightarrow p]$, how to prove it is equivalent to $[ p \lor q]\rightarrow [p\land q]$, I'm new to the logic stuffs, and I feel pretty struggle on it. Need help

Comment: deleted comment since didn't read title carefully. Anyway without truth table one needs to know specifically what rules can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand using $[r\implies s] \equiv [s\ \lor \sim r]$.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. Maybe I missed something. Could you please give me more hints?

Comment: It will mostly involve a lot of applications of De Morgan's laws.

Comment: To start,\begin{align*}
[ p \lor q]\rightarrow [p\land q] &\equiv \sim [ p \lor q] \lor [p\land q] \\
&\equiv [ \sim p \land \sim q] \lor [p\land q] \\
&\equiv \bigg[[ \sim p \land \sim q] \lor [p]\bigg]\land\bigg[[ \sim p \land \sim q] \lor [q]\bigg]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Assume p or q. Case 1:p true. Then from p->q get q true. so have desired conclusion p and q. Case 2:q true. Similar to case 1.

modus ponens used.

I left out the other direction of the overall iff.

Comment: Thank you for your help, how to solve it by using the laws?

Comment: That is a guideline on how to solve it using the laws of natural deduction.